# Excel Index Match with 3 criteria but two columns could move

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a large table of data but to make it simple using the following table how would I get "money" based on site and description? But here's the trick..the table is copied and pasted in the sheet and sometimes description,target and money are flipped around.

So how would I select a column using `INDEX` `MATCH` based on the header? Site is normally static in `A:A` but if there is a way to make that dynamic that would be amazing!!

[image]

Comment: When adding sample data to a post it is prefered to add it as text so others can copy paste it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` `MATCH` to return a column out of a table to pass into another `INDEX` `MATCH`

For your sample data try

```
=INDEX(INDEX($A:$Z,,MATCH(B14,$1:$1,0)),MATCH(C12,INDEX($A:$Z,,MATCH(B12,1:1,0)),0))
```

Ensure the inner `INDEX` range is large enough to cover your table wherever it is (I've used `$A:$Z` in this example)

Breaking it down, `INDEX($A:$Z,,MATCH(B12,1:1,0))` returns the column containing the header value in cell `B12` (`Site` in this case).

Similarly for `INDEX($A:$Z,,MATCH(B13,$1:$1,0))` and `money`

Just make sure the labels in `B12`, `B13` match the table headers exactly (ie `Site`, not `site:`)

---

Based on comment, to match `site` and `description`, try

```
=INDEX(INDEX($A:$Z,,MATCH(B14,1:1,0)),MATCH(1,(INDEX($A:$Z,,MATCH(B13,1:1,0))=C13)*(INDEX($A:$Z,,MATCH(B12,1:1,0))=C12),0))
```

entered as an array formula (press Ctrl-Shift-Enter rather than just Enter)

Comment: Thanks!! but that returned the word "box". I fixed "Site and Description" like you said.

Comment: I know I can use a circular formula =INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(C13=D:D)*(C12=A:A),0)) but I don't know how to expand that for columns that move

Comment: I've edited the formula to refer to `B14` rather than `B13` as that's the `money`.  Sorry.  With multiple duplicate `site` entries this will only ever give you the first match.  If you want multiple criteria you will need a more complex formula.

Answer (score 0):

Chris is awesome! Works great

=INDEX(INDEX($A:$Z,,MATCH(B14,1:1,0)),MATCH(1,(INDEX($A:$Z,,MATCH(B13,1:1,0))=C13)*(INDEX($A:$Z,,MATCH(B12,1:1,0))=C12),0))