# Index and match with multiple criteria and multiple range

Tags: indexing, match, multiple-columns

I have huge list of items from which I am trying to create a dashboard. I tried to use Index and Match - need help with multiple criteria and multiple range while using Index and Match formula. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

attached are the sample photos. Not sure how to upload the sample file here.

formula used is - =INDEX(INDEX(Backend!$G$2:$T$57,,MATCH(Dashboard!E$4,Backend!$G$1:$T$1,0)),MATCH(Dashboard!$B5,INDEX(Backend!$E$2:$E$57,,MATCH($C$2,Backend!$F$9:$F$57,0)),0))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V421B.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHV7T.jpg)

Comment: @chris neilsen - this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468271/excel-index-match-with-3-criteria-but-two-columns-could-move

Comment: how do I attach a sample file in here?

Comment: this is a different issue Nicholas.

Answer (score 0):

IN E5:
=INDEX(Backend!G$2:G$57,MATCH($B5&$C$2,Backend!$E$2:$E$57&Backend!$F$2:$F$57,0))

Confirmed with CSE (Array). Copy down and across.

CSE : Ctrl+Shift+Enter